# PHP : Can't search based on multiple textform

Tags: php

I got a form, where we can search for employee . The form contain textform and checkbox . If we search based on 2 values , ex: `education level` and `course` , the result is only shown based on education level . What should i change with the code ?

**Education level (checkbox)**

```
$education_arr = explode(',', $_POST['txt_lvl_education']);
$total_edulvl = count($education_arr) - 1;
//echo "jum_didik = ".$jum_didik;
if($total_edulvl > 0){
    $d = 0;
    foreach ($education_arr as $value){
        $d++;
        //echo "; value::: ".$value." :::";
        if($d == 1){
            $temp_education.= $value;
        }
        else{
            if($value != ''){
                $temp_education.= ",".$value;
            }
        }
    }

    //$str_didik .= " id_lvl_education IN (".$temp_education.")";

    $sql = "SELECT no_id FROM jobseeker_education WHERE id_lvl_education IN  ".$temp_education.")";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        if($row['no_id'] != ''){
            if(!in_array($row['no_id'], $senarai_kp)){
                array_push($list_id, $row['no_id']);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Course(textform)**

```
$str_course= "";
$course_arr = explode(',', $_POST['txt_course']);
$total_course= count($course_arr);
//echo "jum_didik = ".$jum_didik;
if($total_course> 0){
    $d = 0;
    foreach ($course_arr as $value){
        $d++;
        //echo "; value::: ".$value." :::";
        if($d == 1){
            if($value != ''){

                $str_course.= "  WHERE (LOWER(course) LIKE '%".strtolower(rtrim(ltrim($value)))."%' ";
            }
        }
        else{
            if($value != ''){
                $str_course.= " OR LOWER(course) LIKE '%".strtolower(rtrim(ltrim($value)))."%' ";
            }
        }
    }
    if($str_course!= ''){
        $str_course.= ") ";

        $sql = "SELECT no_id FROM jobseeker_education ".$str_course;
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            if($row['no_kp'] != ''){
                if(!in_array($row['no_id'], $list_id)){
                    array_push($list_id, $row['no_id']);    
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Please show us a final SQL query produced by your (almost impossible to read) code. `echo $sql`.

Comment: Also, as far as I can see, you've got two separate paths of code dealing with the two search scenarios. I'm guessing you need to combine them and generate a single SQL query. Is this your problem?

Comment: You might get more help if you change all code and variable names to english language. It's also a good practice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with multiple "where"

for example

`WHERE name = 'John' AND surname = 'smith' AND username = 'jsmith'`    ...